# Server defined attributes for clients in XMPP

Tags: xmpp

Is it possible to assign attributes to clients in XMPP on the server? I mean something like "XEP-0115: Entity Capabilities", but defined by the server, not by the client. I would like to use this to assign groups to users that they cannot change but request for all clients.

Comment: Where do you envision those attributes to be stored? For example, you could create a PubSub node where the attributes can be read from the clients and only modified by some privileged entity. Not sure if this suits your use case, though.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some way to store this on the server. But yes, I also had the idea of having a "special" client in the network that can give this information. Thanks.

Comment: Well, a pubsub node is basically stored on the server. And you can grant any entity in the XMPP network write access to it, be it a client or a server (or a component).